# Array to display correctly with column headers and values

Tags: php, javascript, html, arrays, curl

How do I get my array to display correctly with column headers and values?  Should I convert the array to a string first somehow?  But then how do I get it to display right with columns and rows?

I'm getting data from a CSV file sent to an array called $data.

$data = curl_exec($ch);

When I echo the $data it looks like this...

```
    CODE: 

echo $data[0];
echo $data[1];
echo $data[2];
echo $data[3];
echo $data[4];
echo $data[5];
echo $data[6];
echo $data[7];
echo $data[8];
echo $data[9];
echo $data[10];
echo $data[11];
echo $data[12];
echo $data[13];
echo $data[14];
echo $data[15];
echo $data[16];
echo $data[17];
echo $data[18];
echo $data[19];
```

OUTPUT:

**"number","priority",**

As you can already tell 0=", 1=n, 2=u, 3=m 4=b, 5=e, 6=r, 7=", 8=, etc. **"number",**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSV file is returned as a string, so accessing `$data[1]` is the same as `substr($data,1,1)`. The simplest way for you to do this would be to save it to a file and then use [`fgetcsv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php):

```
file_put_contents('tmp.csv',$data);
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("tmp.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: or simply using str_getcsv(): http://id.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

Comment: Ooo, that's a relatively new addition to PHP - 5.3.0 and above only - thanks @silent! :)

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone - I'll look into these options :) I really don't have the option to save it locally as a CSV so I have to convert the CSV into a array / string / variable and work from there... I'll see what I can do and thanks again :)

Crap - sorry, I don't have 5.3.0 - I have PHP Version 5.2.17

Comment: **Is there another way besides storing it as a local temp.csv file then reading from it again?  I don't have that option to save the file where I'm running the php from...**

Comment: You can use `str_getcsv()` as recommended by @silent above?

Comment: You can `$data = explode("\n", $data); foreach ($data as $i=>$v) {$data[$i] = explode(',',$v);}` but that won't work for quotes/etc. Best to use a built in csv method. I don't see why you can't save the csv to a file seeing as you're saving your results to a file... you can always `unlink()` it afterwards...

Comment: It's complicated - a company called service-now allows you to save your URL results as CSV files.  I don't have the CSV file myself - they create it for me and I get the live CSV results.   Here is an example - See the **"CSV&"** portion of the URL below:
 
https://demo.service-now.com/task_list.do?CSV&sysparm_userpref_module=1523b8d4c611227b00be8216ec331b9a&sysparm_query=active=true
 
You can use user / pass: admin / admin

Comment: I'll settle...
 

file_put_contents('tmp.csv',$data);
echo "<table border=1>";

$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("tmp.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        // echo "$num fields in line $row: ";
  echo "<tr>";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
   echo "<td>";
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
   echo "</td>";
        }
  echo "</tr>"; 
    }
    fclose($handle);
 
}

 
echo "</table>";